# Index help for bad Query on fairly big table (2m)

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2016, index-tuning, nonclustered-index

I am looking for some assistance please. I have a query that is running against a fairly big table (2 million records).

I have been trying to get the indexes working efficiently. There are a few other queries against this table, but this is by far the most frequent one. I am seriously struggling to get it to execute in under 1 second, and often see it running in 3 to 5 seconds using profiler.

It might be as fast as can be, but I would appreciate some input to confirm/deny that please.

Just a note: Dev wont change the query or schema at all. Optimizations can be made in the database only, and no schema changes.

The Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Notifications](
[ntID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
[NotificationID] [int] NOT NULL,
[NotificationType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CreatedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
[Status] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Result] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Extension] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ShiftRate] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[ResponseMinutes] [int] NULL,
[ResponseWindow] [datetime] NULL,
[caNotificationID] [int] NULL,
[AwardedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[AwardedOn] [datetime] NULL,
[CancelledBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CancelledOn] [datetime] NULL,
[CancelledReasonID] [int] NULL,
[CancelledReasonText] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[AwardingDate] [datetime] NULL,
[ScheduledLaunchDate] [datetime] NULL,
[CustomMessage] [nvarchar](160) NULL,
[SystemName] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
[AutoClose] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ESP_Notifications_ntID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ntID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ESP_Notifications] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [AutoClose]
GO
```

Table Data snapshot:

[image: screenshot of sample data]

The Query:

```
Update Notifications 
  set Status = 'Awarding' OUTPUT deleted.* 
where ntID = (
    select top(1) ntID 
    from Notifications 
    where NotificationType = 'Shift' 
      and (Status = 'Done') 
      and ResponseWindow < '2019-02-04 10:40:03' 
    order by ntID)
```

Attempted Indexes :

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_Notifications_Status_NotificationType_ResponseWindow_ntID] 
ON [dbo].[Notifications](
   [Status] ASC,[NotificationType] ASC,[ResponseWindow] DESC,[ntID] DESC
)

CREATE INDEX [IX_Notifications_Status_ScheduledLaunchDate_ntID] 
ON [dbo].[Notifications](
    [ScheduledLaunchDate] DESC,[Status] ASC,[ntID] ASC
)

CREATE INDEX [IX_Notifications_NotificationType_caNotificationID_NotificationID_ntID] 
ON [dbo].[Notifications](
   [NotificationType] DESC, [caNotificationID] DESC, [NotificationID] DESC, [ntID] DESC
);
```

NotificationType contains 3 different types, of which 70% are type 'Shift'
Status has 10 types, but the 'In Flight' records are only about 100 to 200, split over 4 Status's

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the subquery in that update consistently uses those two predicate values, a filtered index should help a lot.  Something like this (which [Erik Darling](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/32281/erik-darling) kindly provided as a comment):

```
CREATE INDEX IX_ntID_ResponseWindow_Includes ON dbo.Notifications (ntID, ResponseWindow) 
INCLUDE (NotificationType, Status) 
WHERE (Status = 'Done' AND NotificationType = 'Shift');
```

This will let the subquery find the relevant group of IDs that match `Status` and `NotificationType` (as they are the only rows in the index) and avoid sorting the data (since it's already ordered by ntID as the leading column in the index).

It *will* still have to check the `ResponseWindow` value on each row.  In the worst case, if there are no rows that meet the date requirement for the query (or if the first match has a very high ntID), most or all of the index will be read. 
  Which makes the effectiveness of this approach limited depending on data distribution.